# React, Use navbar layout for every page with the exception of homepage

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This will probably be a very stupid question for anyone already working with react. However, I started exploring react features recently and I can't seem to find a way to extend my layout to just a few components. I tried some things already mentioned in other posts like using props.location but I was unsuccessful. Currently my layout is being extended to all pages but I would like to make a different navbar for the home page.
I also tried to do this in some ways with IF'S and ELSES depending on the pathnames but I was unsuccessful. Would anyone have any tips on how to proceed? I really don't know which way to think.
My files are currently organized as follows:

```
App = () => ( 
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Layout>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
          <Route exact path='/about' component={About} />
          <Route exact path='/contact' component={Contact} />
          <Route exact path='/listings' component={Listings} />
          <PrivateRoute exact path='/listings/:id' component={ListingDetail} />
          <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
          <Route exact path='/signup' component={SignUp} />
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>  
      </Layout>
    </Router>
</Provider>
);
```

My layout:

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar';




const layout = (props) => (
<div>
    <Navbar/>
   
    {props.children}
</div>
);

export default layout;
```

My index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
<React.StrictMode>
<App />
</React.StrictMode>,
document.getElementById('root')
);


reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried with `props.location`? Did you confirm that value is what you expect?

Answer (score 3):

You can use nested `Switch` tags for this, where the first level only decides whether you want the nav bar or not, and the second level decides the sub-route to render. For example:

```
const WithNavbar = () => <Layout>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/about' component={About} />
    <Route exact path='/contact' component={Contact} />
    <Route exact path='/listings' component={Listings} />
    <PrivateRoute exact path='/listings/:id' component={ListingDetail} />
    <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
    <Route exact path='/signup' component={SignUp} />
    <Route component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
</Layout>;

App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route component={WithNavbar} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);
```

Comment: Yes, just what i needed. Thanks for that.
I was trying to remodel my app.js but due to the fact that the layout was using props.children I was experiencing some errors.