# How to not render Layout component on NextJS login page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

How can exclude render of `Layout` component when the route is `/login`, `/register` etc... in NextJS?

```
const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

What I have done so far inside `Layout.js`

```
const router = useRouter();

if (router.pathname.includes('/login')) return children;
if (router.pathname.includes('/register')) return children;
```

EDIT:
the above solution works, just wanted to know if nextjs routing provides a "good practice" way to solve this problem

Comment: What is wrong with your current approach?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React, Use navbar layout for every page with the exception of homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67426171/react-use-navbar-layout-for-every-page-with-the-exception-of-homepage)

Comment: @ChristianFritz I am afraid routing doesn't work that way in NextJS

Comment: i think for now your solution is good or you can do remove a component from the layout which you want to exclude and put that component on every page.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps to exclude a specific component from layout. This will exclude the dashboard component from the layout.

1. Add "Dashboard.getLayout" function in the component you want to
   exclude.

```
 const Dashboard = ({ children }) => {
return (
  <>
  <DashboardContent children={''}/>
  </>
);
};

export default Dashboard;

Dashboard.getLayout = function PageLayout(page) {
return (
    <>
        {page}
    </>
)
}
```

2. Add below code in your _app.js component file.

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
if (Component.getLayout) {
return Component.getLayout(
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    )
}
return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```