# How to hide header only at one page in nextjs app?

Tags: next.js

I work on Nextjs apllication, I've created `<Header />` component and added it to `_app.tsx` file but i don't need it displayed only at one page, could you please tell me is it possible ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a wrapper component you can check the pathname and render conditionally the `<Header />`

```
import { Fragment } from "react";
import MainHeader from "./../layout/main-header";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

function Layout(props) {
  const router = useRouter();

  const showHeader = router.pathname === "/admin" ? false : true;
  return (
    <Fragment>
        {showHeader && <MainHeader />}
        <main>{props.children}</main>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can get the current route with the [useRouter hook](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#userouter).  You'll likely want to check against [`asPath`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object) because `pathname` will not match dynamic or catch-all routes. It's a simple way to future-proof your check.

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const { asPath } = useRouter();
return (
   <>
     {asPath !== '/some-route' && <Header/>}
   </>
)
```

You can also use a layout pattern similar to [option 4](https://adamwathan.me/2019/10/17/persistent-layout-patterns-in-nextjs/).  Your default layout can be your current layout. You can make an additional header-less layout for your pages that don't need a header.

Comment: Consider using `pathname` instead of `asPath`, so you can exclude the query part of the URL.

Comment: you can check the better way of doing this by following this link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74559731/13625459

Comment: @ankit - you don't want to do that - it will conflict with next 13 layouts. Also, next 13 solves the OP's question out of the box. This was for next 10/11/12.

Answer (score 0):

With the Next.js App router, you can use the Multiple Root Layout Concept to achieve it better. That way you do not have to make any of the page components as the client component.

You can use the route grouping to handle different layouts for different pages. That way you can avoid header and footer in some layouts easily at the layout level.

Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups